# FastText and CharEmbedding

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, word2vec, word-embeddings, embeddings

i have got a question. i don't understand how to develop my DLModel.
I'm working on DGA Detection with this type of dataset:

```
1,d o m a i n 1
0,d o m a i n 2
1,d o m a i n 3
....
```

1 for dga and 0 for legit domain.

so i trained fasttext that gave me vector rapresentation for every char i have got in my dataset (39 char).

Than i would like to train this model

```
model.add(layers.LSTM(128))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

but when i try to fit my model with:

```
model.fit(xtrain,y_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,epochs=EPOCHS,callbacks=callbacks_list,verbose=1)
```

i had always error:

```
indices[7,1] = 39 is not [0,39]
```

i think that depends from shape of my input and output but i can't figure out where is the problem.
For example my
xtrain shape is (79998, 143) --> every line is a domain, ad 143 is the max input.
weight matrix is (39, 100)

i'm new to this studies and i'm really glad if someone could help me!

thanks!